# How to do press any key to continue prompt?

Tags: c++, cin

I am writing a program where the code reads off the text from a .txt file in where anything more than 24 lines must be continued with the enter key, but unsure how to put in the prompt asking for the enter key that doesn't mess up the formatting as it must show the first 24 lines instantly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
....    

{
    cout << "Please enter the name of the file: ";
    string fileName;
    getline(cin, fileName);

    ifstream file(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);

    string input;
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    int count = 0;

    while (getline(fin, input))
    {
        cout << count << ". " << input << '\n' ;
        count++;
        if (count % 25 == 0)
            cin.get();
    }
    cin.get();
    system("read");
    return 0;
}
```

The part of the code that does the function and if I insert the prompt into here

```
if (count % 25 == 0)
cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
cin.get();
```

it just has it where you must press enter for each line. Putting the prompt anywhere just messes it up in other ways.

Comment: please post a [mcve], actual and desired output

Comment: Try to reformat your code with the prompt: The `cin.get()` call isn't in the `if` statements body.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I got it to work properly @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: You don't need more than `ifstream file(fileName);` for opening the file. There have been `std::string` constructors for ages, and `ios::in` is implied by the "i" in "ifstream".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place braces `{}` for the appropriate `if` (as pointed out in the comments) and your program will work.

Note also that there is no need to use `ifstream` twice as you did in your program.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
   
int main()
{

    std::string fileName;
    std::cout<<"Enter filename"<<std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, fileName);
    
    std::ifstream file(fileName);

    std::string line;
    int count = 1;
    if(file)
    {
        while (std::getline(file, line))
        {
            std::cout << count << ". " << line << '\n' ;
            
            if (count % 25 == 0)
            {
               std::cout<<"Press enter to continue"<<std::endl;
                std::cin.get();
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
    }
      
    return 0;
}
```